# Wordpress Plugin - Expose REST API

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to write a plugin that would add these endpoints  `GET, POST, DELETE /api/checked` to access the plugin's custom table.

Is it possible for a Wordpress plugin to expose a RESTful API? I can't seem to find any examples or documentation.

The closest thing I found was `add_rewrite_rule`. I was able to create `http://www.blog.com/api`, but how do I determine the HTTP verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WP REST API. Just install it and then go to settings -> permalink and add /%postname%/ on the last field.

then you'll have everything you need at [url]/json-api/

[Here](http://wp-api.org/) is the doc

Comment: thanks for the link. i'm trying the sample code in "Extending the API" but the routes I create all show up as "Post Not Found". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON-API` WordPress plugin for creating the web-services that can be used for fetching the data from Wordpress.

And the plugin will provide the webservice url something like that :

`www.mysite.com/api/servicename`

Plugin link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Hope it helps you some extent.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I considered using this plugin but it doesn't seem possible to extend it for custom tables

Comment: you can extend this plugin very easily and this plugin also allows to create custom controller / service too.

Comment: Check it out here for more clarification : http://bitsandbabble.com/2013/10/build-a-custom-wordpress-json-api-controller/